# Git Checkout Deleting And Modifying Files

Tags: git, git-bash

First of all, I see there are some questions on this topic and I've gone through them but now been able to solve my problem.  Most other questions seem to relate to EOL and my case seems to have more to it.

**Problem:** `git checkout` is modifying and deleting files.

I ran into this issue and started by cloning a new copy of the repository this morning, so there have been a limited amount of changes to this particular git repo at this point.

Env:

- Using Git Bash terminal running in ConEmu on Windows 10
- Have Visual Code open which has a git source tab
- Have GitKraken open which is a git management application
- `git --version` = "git version 2.23.0.windows.1"
- `git config --get core.autocrlf` = "true"

Listed other running git related applications as I feel that could be contributing in some fashion

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have done the following:

1. Reset my candidate branch as I had a changed file
2. Done a `git status` to demonstrate that there are no changed files in the local candidate branch
3. Done a checkout on a feature branch (PDEV-937).  This is someone else's feature branch I pulled from origin.
4. `git status` to show that I have changes in my working directory somehow. These changes seem to be deleted files or files that have been modified by deleting all contents (one empty line left).

[image]

I can't explain the file modification on checkout and the most frustrating part of is that nothing is done consistently.  Immediately after the first screenshot I tried to reset the feature branch to match origin. You can see that each reset achieved a different state (I continued resetting and after two more calls I had a working directly with no changes finally).

[image]

My desired outcome is that a git checkout doesn't modify or delete any files (this is my expectation)

**Update:** It seems I only run into this problem when checking out another specific developer's branches for code review.  He uses Linux and I use Windows although I haven't figured out how that is causing the problem; it's also very consistent.  I can clone the repo, do a checkout of a specific feature branch and everything is fine.  Do a few cherry-pick/reset/merges on that branch and then the next feature branch I checkout will be modifying files again. Clone the repo fresh and checkout the second feature and it will be fine again.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the repository has files with the same name, but different cases. You can verify with `git ls-files`.

Here's a demonstration on OS X. OS X is case-insensitive by default, but I've made a case-sensitive filesystem to create a test repository.

```
$ cd /Volumes/CaseSensitive/tmp/
$ git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /Volumes/CaseSensitive/tmp/test/.git/
$ cd test
$ echo 'lowercase' > foo
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'lowercase file'
$ git checkout -b upcase
$ echo 'uppercase' > Foo
$ git commit -m 'uppercase file'
```

We have a repository with `foo` in the master branch and both `foo` and `Foo` in the `upcase` branch. Let's clone it to a case-insensitive filesystem.

```
$ git clone /Volumes/CaseSensitive/tmp/test
Cloning into 'test'...
done.

$ cd test
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Everything is fine on the `master` branch with just `foo`. Now watch when we check out `upcase` branch with both `foo` and `Foo`.

```
$ git checkout upcase
Switched to branch 'upcase'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/upcase'.

$ git status
On branch upcase
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/upcase'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   foo

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git ls-files
Foo
foo
```

Git tries to put both files onto the disk, but one overwrites the other.

---

The only real solution is to not have files with the same name but different case. Get on a case-sensitive filesystem and rename those files. You can [try making the directories case-sensitive](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/).

Comment: I appreciate the details and this makes total sense but doesn't seem to be the cause in my case.  I only see a single named version of the files that are changing on checkout and to throw a wrench into things, deleting the feature branch and going another checkout can actually result in different files being modified/deleted than the first time.

Comment: @Daniel Odd. If you do figure out out, please post an answer.